# Make HTTP GET from fulfillment in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, fulfillment

I'm trying to make my own google action and I want to call an external api to get responses.

Here is my code:

```
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = conversation({debug:true});
const https = require('https');

app.handle('Tester', conv => {
  // Implement your code here
  conv.add("ok it works");
});

app.handle('Tester2', conv => {
  // Implement your code here
  let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?_limit=2';
  //const url = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";
  
  http_req(url).then((message)=> {
    console.log(message[0].name);
      conv.add(message[0].name);
    //return Promise.resolve();
  });
});

function http_req(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      https.get(url, function(resp) {
          var json = "";
          resp.on("data", function(chunk) {
              //console.log("received JSON response: " + chunk);
              json += chunk;
          });

          resp.on("end", function() {
              let jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
                                console.log(jsonData[0].name);
                resolve(jsonData);
          });
      }).on("error", (err) => {
          reject("Error: " + err.message);
      });
  });
}

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The logs:
[image]

Error text:

```
Error: Response has already been sent. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?
```

The problem is that the assistant won't say the conv.add(message[0].name); (obviusly it has a value)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a reddit user
https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/lia5r4/make_http_get_from_fulfillment_in_nodejs/gn23hi3?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

> This error messages tells you just about all you need to know! Your
> call to con.add() is indeed being used in an asynchronous call (the
> callback chained to the Promise you created from http_req), and you
> are indeed not returning that Promise.
>
> Here's what's happening:
>
> Google calls your 'Tester2' handler
>
> You start an asynchronous HTTP request via http_req, encapsulated in a
> Promise
>
> Your function completes before the HTTP request does
>
> Google sees that you are not returning anything from your handler and
> assumes that you're done, so it sends the Response
>
> The HTTP request finishes and its Promise resolves, calling your code
> attached by the then() function
>
> The simple solution here is to return the Promise created by your
> http_req(...).then(...) code, so Google will know that you're not just
> quite done, and it should wait for that Promise to resolve before
> sending the Response.
>
> If you can use async/await it becomes a bit clearer:

```
app.handle('Tester2', async conv => {
  // Implement your code here
  let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?_limit=2';
  //const url = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";

  const message = await http_req(url);
  console.log(message[0].name);
  conv.add(message[0].name);
});
```